# Integrating Bootstrap 3 Typeahead with Bootstrap Tagsinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm trying to integrate the [Bootstrap 3 Typeahead plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) (basically a port from the old Bootstrap typeahead functionality before it was removed in Bootstrap 3, if I understand correctly) with the [Bootstrap-Tagsinput plugin](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/).

I have no problem getting these to work individually, including the JSON prefetch typeahead functionality.  I do not understand how to integrate the two.  I don't think it should be too hard but my knowledge of Javascript is apparently lacking.

Here is my input field:

`<input type="text" id="tagFilter" data-provide="typeahead" data-role="tagsinput">`

And here is the way the typeahead plugin is called in Javascript:

```
//The typeahead
$.get('tags.php', function(data){
    $("#tagFilter").typeahead({ source:data });
    },'json');
```

If it's helpful, the Tagsinput has an example in its docs explaining how to implement twitter typeahead.js:

```
$('input').tagsinput();

// Adding custom typeahead support using http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js
$('input').tagsinput('input').typeahead({
  prefetch: 'citynames.json'
}).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {  
  this.tagsinput('add', datum.value);
  this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
}, $('input')));
```

But I'm using a different plugin.  I found that one to be over my head.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay...so I've actually decided on using the Twitter typeahead.js, as I managed to get it working.  I used the following code, please someone point out if it's not the best way to do it.

`<input type="text" id="tagFilter" data-provide="typeahead" value="test,arlington">`

```
$('#tagFilter').tagsinput({
    typeahead: {
       source: $.get('tags.php')
    }
    });
```

My tags.php file is just a list, I think it will take a lot more work to get this to function with an associative array with keys in the JSON file.  I decided there was no benefit to this in my case, as I'm only concerned with the tag names for query purposes.

So my tags.php is just echoing the result of:

```
//the mySQLi query is above...
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tags[] = $row['tag_name'];

    }
echo json_encode($tags);
```

Hope someone can benefit.